# Поиск записей в подчиненной таблице MSSQL

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте всем! 
Имеем две таблицы Master и Detail, таблицы соединены по ключу FK, и соответственно имеем два грида, у одно в качестве DataSource - masterBindigSource. у второго соответсвенно - FKbindingSource.

Вроде всё логично и работает, но при вызове метода FKbindingSource.Find() вылетает исключение, о невозможности найти указанный столбец.

Вопрос, как организовать поиск записи в подчинённой таблице?

Comment: Покажите код. Если все логично - то должно работать и так :)

Comment: string ci = e.ClickedItem.Text.ToString();
            fKHoleTableMainTableBindingSource.Position = fKHoleTableMainTableBindingSource.Find("Out_No", e.ClickedItem.Text.ToString());

Comment: отредактируйте вопрос и вставьте в него полный код для воспроизведения проблемы

Comment: скорее всего вы просто с именем колонки ошибилсь

Comment: Да нет, тут известная проблема поиска в BindinSource если он привязан к Relation, необходимо использовать перегруженный метод Find, внятного примера найти не могу

Comment: приведите нормальный пример для воспроизведения проблемы.